# Flutter displaying any Svg Image

Tags: flutter, svg, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add use SVG images for an Application I am working on but  flutter is not loading or diplaying those pictures:

I have a model from which the images are fetched

**Here is the model**

```
class CategoryModel {
  final String categoryType;
  final String categoryImage;

  CategoryModel({
    required this.categoryType,
    required this.categoryImage,
  });
}

List<CategoryModel> categoryList = [
  CategoryModel(
    categoryType: 'Add',
    categoryImage: 'assets/images/CirclesFour.svg',
  ),
  CategoryModel(
    categoryType: 'All',
    categoryImage: 'assets/images/CirclesFour.svg',
  ),
  CategoryModel(
    categoryType: 'Mobiles',
    categoryImage: 'assets/images/mobileImage.svg',
  ),
  CategoryModel(
    categoryType: 'Laptop',
    categoryImage: 'assets/images/laptopImage.svg',
  ),
  CategoryModel(
    categoryType: 'Electronics',
    categoryImage: 'assets/images/electronicsImage.svg',
  ),
];
```

I have also tried using Svgpicture.asset in the above code but that did not work for me so i used **string** type

**The images are being called here in the below widget**

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SizedBox(
      height: size.height * 0.14,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: categoryList.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    radius: 30,
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      categoryList[index].categoryImage,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: size.height * 0.005,
                ),
                Text(categoryList[index].categoryType),
              ],
            );
          },
       ),
    );
```

I have imported `flutter_svg` package
Instead of Circle Avatar I have also tried using container but nothing seems to work
the address is correct
the 1 categoryModel which is **ADD** is working not as i want but is working.

here is an image of my assets :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify that SVG files are correctly placed in the assets folder and ensure that
   thefile paths specified in CategoryModel class match the correct file locations.
2. Check that you have added the correct dependencies in your pubspec.yaml file for
   handling SVG images.

   ```
    dependencies:
        flutter_svg: ^x.xx.x
   ```
3. Make sure you have imported the flutter_svg package:

   ```
     import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
   ```
4. Ensure that your Flutter project is aware of the assets by adding them to
   pubspec.yaml file under the flutter section:

   ```
    flutter:
      assets:
        - assets/images/
   ```
5. If using hot reload, try restarting your application

Finally, if the issue is not resolved, consider trying to use a different SVG image or converting the SVG files to a different format, such as PNG/JPG, to see if they load correctly.

Comment: i have added the package and imported it as well but its still not loading would using PNG result in low quality image